# Dont see object id that is inside a list of objects beanie odm

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi

I have the following code for the Beanie ODM (for Python):

```
class PlanetDocument(Document):
    created_at: datetime

    name: str = "Planet"


class UserDocument(Document):
    id: Indexed(str)
    username: Optional[str] = None

    planets: List[PlanetDocument] = []

    class Settings:
        name = "user"
```

When I store a PlanetDocument, I can see it has it's id, but when I store the same planet on the UserDocument planets list the object doesnt has id, I store it in user the following way:

```
user = await UserDocument.get(planet_data.user)

new_planet = PlanetDocument("time", "name")
new_planet = await new_planet.create()

user.planets.append(new_planet)
await user.save()
```

Then I lookup user[0].planets[0] and it has not it's id set

Answer (score 1):

This solved my issue:

https://roman-right.github.io/beanie/tutorial/relations/

Instead of using normal typing, I missed to setup relation by using Link.